# Creating a reusable audio view / component

Tags: ember.js

The JSON I get from the server includes a `playable-url` property:

```
{
    ...
    "text" : "Audio transcription",
    "playable-url" : 'http://myserver.com/full/path/audio.wav"
    ....
}
```

I receive a list which I am showing in a tabular format. In one of the columns I want to show an html element to allow the user to listen to the audio. For that I am planning on generating markup for the [audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp):

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

But I am not sure whether it is better to provide a [`View`](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/) or a [`Component`](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/defining-a-component/) for this.

What would be the best approach? Is there any example of audio View / Component that I could use to base my implementation on?

Comment: Perfect for a component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Component. Creating a custom View here is not necessary since you don't need to handle any advanced user events. Something along the following should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/3DvXm/

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/music-file">
    <audio controls>
        <source {{bind-attr src=source.mp3}} type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Audio Component</h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{music-file source=model}}
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return {
        mp3: 'https://archive.org/download/onclassical-quality-wav-audio-files-of-classical-music/onclassical_demo_fiati-di-parma_thuille_terzo-tempo_sestetto_small-version_64kb.mp3'
    };
  }
});
```